# update statement with replace in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replace, postgresql-9.2

I have table having below records

```
Sno  A
-    --
1   spoo74399p 
2   spoo75399p
```

I want to update the above records by replacing oo (alphabet 'o') by empty after sp
 afte
    Required OUTPUT
    ----------------
    Sno     A

```
1   sp74399p 
2   sp75399p
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET A = REPLACE(A, 'spoo', 'sp');
```

This would update all the records.

To clarify a bit, this would find any instances of "spoo" and replace them with "sp". The end result is that any "oo" right after "sp" would be deleted.

Comment: i think sp should not come.'oo' replaced by empty.so Replace(A,'oo','').is it correct?

Comment: @Ram You can also replace 'oo' with ''. It's just a rule of thumb to replace the longer sequence. This way if you find 'oo' in a different part of the string, it will not be replaced.

Comment: if i put sp in replace command it replace the 'oo' by 'sp'.but i want to replace 'oo' with empty.so pls give the update command for this.

Comment: If you want to replace oo with empty after sp, use the command in my answer.
If you want to replace any oo with empty, use `REPLACE(A, 'oo', '')`.